# Facebook Graph API - video upload issue

Tags: facebook-graph-api, video

I'm using a manual flow to get the code and auth_token through the Graph API. I can post messages from our Python server without any issue.
When trying to post a video to Graph, I keep getting this error:
{"error":{"message":"(#352) Sorry, the video file you selected is in a format that we don't support.","type":"OAuthException","code":352}}.

I use endpoint https://graph-video.facebook.com/FB-ID-HERE/videos
I've tried multiple MP4 and WMV files.

The code:

```
source_video = open(video_path, 'rb').read()
values = {'access_token': facebook_request.auth_token,
          # 'source': source_video,
          'description': arg_description,
          'title': arg_title}

response = requests.post(url, data=values, files=dict(source=source_video), verify=False).text
```

I've been working according to this guide: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/videos.

Am I missing something?
Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: having the same issue, did you ever figure it out?